# While updating my maven project, I get the following error "Failed while installing JAX-RS"

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jax-rs

I get the following error:

```
Failed while installing JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 1.1.
org.osgi.service.prefs.BackingStoreException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Also, while running the project on apache server, a classnotfound exception is thrown by the jersey servlet.

Comment: That error occurs due to a badly formatted XML file. Could you please update your answer with the XML file you're trying to parse?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is mostly caused due to a typo in XML element. Can you please paste the part of your dependency for JAX-RS (Jersey) in pom.xml.